# What does =INDIRECT(!$F12) mean in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm reviewing a model, where I keep on seeing the exclamation mark used before the cell letter name - as presented in the question header," =INDIRECT(!$F12) " 
What does it mean? how it works? can someone please help me where can I read about such references?
this is used in naming cell
another formula made the same way 
=IF(!N$7

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you by any chance looking in the Name Manager or in VBA code?  You should not see an exclamation mark without a sheet name on the worksheet, itself.  If you're seeing it on the worksheet, that would probably indicate a formula creation error.

That nomenclature can be used when defining a named range in the Name Manager.  The exclamation mark connects the sheet name with the cell address.  But if you have a case where the same named range is defined on multiple sheets, this method can be used to create a "generic" sheet reference.  The named range is defined using the exclamation mark but no sheet name.  When you use that named range on a specific worksheet, it will refer to the range on the active worksheet.

You can read more about this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27037152/what-does-an-exclamation-mark-before-a-cell-reference-mean) and [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-the-exclamation-mark-in-Excel).